# How to define limsup of a function

Tags: analysis

Let $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$. What is the definition of 
$$ \limsup_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$$ for $a \in [0, \infty)$?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Functions_from_metric_spaces_to_metric_spaces).

Comment: Given that all the definitions offered (Wikipedia link, answer below) put the focus on neighborhood formulations, I thought I would mention that I find it much easier to intuitively grasp and work with the notion $\limsup_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ by thinking of it as the largest of the functional values you can get when using sequences that approach $a$ (where none of the terms of the sequence can be equal to $a$). Of course, one would first say "supremum of the" and then prove that the supremum can always be achived for some sequence.

Answer (score 1):

This definition is given in some books:
$$\limsup_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=\inf_{0<r}\sup_{x\in ((a-r)\cup(a+r))\cap[0,\infty)}f(x)$$

or simply:
$$\limsup_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=\inf_{0<\epsilon}\space\space\sup_{0<|x-a|<\epsilon}f(x)$$

This is the deleted upper limit. Undeleted one is defined by:

$$Limsup_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=\inf_{0<\epsilon}\space\space\sup_{|x-a|<\epsilon}f(x)$$